# OWL API Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader

Tags: exception

OWL API 
when I write an

```
OWLOntologyManager man = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
```

the exception like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.vocab.OWLFacet.<init>(OWLFacet.java:87)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.vocab.OWLFacet.<clinit>(OWLFacet.java:60)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.vocab.OWL2Datatype$Category.<clinit>(OWL2Datatype.java:328)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.vocab.OWL2Datatype.<clinit>(OWL2Datatype.java:74)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.InternalsNoCache.<clinit>(InternalsNoCache.java:59)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLDataFactoryImpl.<init>(OWLDataFactoryImpl.java:128)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLDataFactoryImpl.<clinit>(OWLDataFactoryImpl.java:74)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.getOWLDataFactory(OWLManager.java:150)
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager(OWLManager.java:111)
    at amain.main(amain.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: when i change the jar to OWL API 3.5.0 it is fixed.... but the higher version still has the problem

Comment: I just had exactly the same problem as you. I think this needs to be reported as an issue on GitHub.